# Remove column from variable before adding to table

Tags: jquery

```
$newRow = $('<tr>').append($('#active_participant'+participant_row)
    .clone()).remove().html();                          
$($newRow).find('td[name="state"]').remove();
```

I have this code. The `$newRow =` line works fine. But the second line doesn't.

What I want to do is find a row in a table(first line above. OK). I then want to remove the `td` state from `$newRow` before adding `$newRow` to another table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing your markup. But a `td` surely should not have a `name` attribute, only form elements can have that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a `td` element via its name. I can't imagine that in this case it'll have a name attribute. The best way would probably be to identify it by its class, or its [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector.